# Eclipse rcp: Store log4j log in application directory

Tags: log4j, eclipse-rcp

So I'm almost finished with my journey through log4j land. I have one more question. When configuring log4j with a property file I can set a location to write the log file to via:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\log.html
```

How do I change this path to reflect a relative path in my application?
Using

```
log4j.appender.file.File=log.html
```

did not generate the log file at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong place. If I use a relative path it is getting placed in my eclispe working directory. I assume that after exporting the product the path will be reltive to the product.